# If I get a row from Database with Room and LiveData, how can I "synchronize" it with a variable in the UI thread?

Tags: java, android, android-room

The example:
selectedCode.something() gives error, because selectedCode is null, it has not initialized in the other thread, but I don't want the whole section to write in the changed method of Observable.
Maybe there is an other way to do this?

```
public class CodeDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Code selectedCode;
    private CodeRepository mCodeRepository;

   private void retrieve(final int id){
            mCodeRepository.retrieveCode(id).observe(this, new Observer<Code>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Code code) {
                    if (code != null){
                        selectedCode = code;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_code_details);
             

           retrieveCode(1);
           selectedCode.something();
```

Comment: What does "the whole section to write" mean? It looks like you just need to move `seelctedCode.something()` to be in `onChanged()`, after your current `selectedCode = code;` line.

Comment: retrieveCode(1) and selectedCode.something() are in an if statement. And after the there is another code. But maybe I will refractor it a bit and check that way. Thanks.